# How to add image in Highcharts.If no data available

Tags: image, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/akb4Lj61

I'm trying to add images in chart  using Highcharts.I doubt whether highcharts support images .i want to import image in empty content.Any help would be appreciated.Thank you in advance.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'bubble',
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    zoomType: 'xy'
},

title: {
    text: 'No Date Availavle'
},
});
```

Comment: I wouldnt print the chart at all, put a `<img>` instead (when you process your template server-side or in javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/akb4Lj61/3/

Here's an updated jsfiddle, you just have to add

```
renderer.image('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png', 100, 100, 30, 30)
.add();
```

To your chart, put the url, x position, y position and height, width as parameters.